# Is it possible to save dataflow exports to Salesforce records?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, dataflow

I have built a connection between NetSuite and Salesforce using the Data Manager from Analytics Studio. I have a column of data from NetSuite I would like to save (ideally automatically) to a corresponding field on Salesforce Contact records.

I also built a dashboard with the inner joined data from both sources that I display in an analytics dashboard. I was hoping I could save the value using quick actions from contact object, but I am not sure what action would pick up the value from the column and update the record.

Is it at all possible to save the external column onto Salesforce records? And if so how?

**Update:** There is an SDK for Analytics, I'm running experiments to see how I can extract data through it. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_overview.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Analytics SDK proved useful, in the end I wrote a class with a method that takes for arguments the developername of the dataset as `datasetName` and the dataset API column names of the salesforce record ID as `contactIdColumn` and the NetSuite field as `netsuiteColumn`. Here is an example with the Contact object.

```apex
public void syncContactsWithNetSuite(String datasetName, String contactIdColumn, String netsuiteColumn) {
    // Build and execute query
    Wave.ProjectionNode[] projections = new Wave.ProjectionNode[]{
        Wave.QueryBuilder.get('\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(contactIdColumn) + '\'')
                        .alias(Contact.Id.getDescribe().getName()),
        Wave.QueryBuilder.get('\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(netsuiteColumn) + '\'')
                        .alias(Contact.NetSuite_Custom_Field__c.getDescribe().getName())
        };
    ConnectApi.LiteralJson result = Wave.QueryBuilder.loadByDeveloperName(datasetName)
        .foreach(projections)
        .cap(Limits.getLimitDmlStatements())
        .execute('q');
    String response = result.json;
    // Parse JSON response
    List<Contact> records = MyUtility.jsonParseOutContactData(response);
    // Update all records
    Database.update(records, false);
}
```